# Unable to get element error using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is a weird one, I am trying to get product names and price from a website using selenium in Python. I am able to get the price but getting the unable to locate element error for product name.

[image]

I am using very similar code for both these items :

```
s3 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.weight-tile__PriceText-otzu8j-5.hJFddt")

print(s3.text)

s = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.mobile-product-list-item__ProductName-zxgt1n-6.hBmGOx")

print(s.text)
```

Comment: Show us the html code for the elements you expect to find.  Don't make us click on a website link.

Comment: I have added an image with the html

Comment: Please don't post *images* of text; just include the text itself (formatted as a code sample when appropriate).

Comment: XPATH - //div[@class="desktop-product-list-item__Container-sc-8wto4u-0 jTzrhU"]//div[@class="desktop-product-list-item__ProductNameContainer-sc-8wto4u-12 bMVVKM"]//span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css selector is trying to find the class which is valid for mobile size. If you want to find the element, make sure that the browser has mobile dimensions. Or if you want to catch the titles in the desktop version, in your case it is

```
s = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.desktop-product-list-item__ProductName-sc-8wto4u-7.kjymBK")
```

Answer (score 1):

The *classname* attribute values like *`hJFddt`*, *`hBmGOx`* are dynamically generated and is bound to change sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

To extract the ***prices*** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://https://dutchie.com/embedded-menu/the-circle/products/flower?)
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class^='desktop-product-list-item__ProductName']")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://https://dutchie.com/embedded-menu/the-circle/products/flower?)
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[starts-with(@class, 'desktop-product-list-item__ProductName')]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Cannabiotix | The Silk | 3.5g', 'HEX | Lemon Cherry Gelato | 3.5g', 'A Golden State | Garlic Blossom | 3.5g', 'Alien Labs | OZ Kush | 3.5g']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```